# Deploying software through group policy

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to deploy an MSI to a specific security group that has all computer members.

I've set the GPO to install via the UNC path, and it's a computer configuration.  I've also made sure that everyone has read&execute to that domain share.  Once I save the policy I reboot the test VM in the security group, and nothing changes.  The policy is linked to the OU the security group is in, and the policy is enforced.

I suspect the problem is with the scope, as gpresult isn't even showing the policy.

Since my OU is broken down like this

```
Domain
-Department
--Computers (where the computers in the security OU are)
--Groups (where the security OU is)
--Users
```

I linked the GPO to the Department and enforced it there.

Any thoughts?

e;

So...I'm a dunce.  My test VM was still in my test OU, not my department->Computers OU.

Thanks for letting me talk through my problem.

Comment: What do rsop and gpresult say about the GPO in question?  That's where you're gonna find your answer, 11 out of 10 times.

Comment: You can post your answer as an Answer to this question and mark it as accepted. This will help tidy up this question for the future, and better lead people to the actual problem... verifying your object is where you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My test VM was still in my test OU, not my department->Computers OU.

Therefore the GPO wasn't applied to that object, even though it was applied to a security group that my object was a part of.  GPO is weird sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, we've all been there. Please be sure to [mark your answer as accepted when you're able](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).